# C++: Assigning different parts of input to different variables

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, fractions

I'm writing a program that has to perform operations with fractions, and the user has to be able to input the expression in the form w/x (operator) y/z. (i.e. 1/2 + 1/4.)
How can I take that input and assign different parts of it to different variables, namely the numerators, denominators, and operator?

Comment: @NominSim:  The [homework] tag has been banned.

Comment: @JohnDibling Whoops, didn't know that.

Comment: Can you post your attempt at the solution?

Comment: I tried (and failed) this with cin statements because my professor said this could be done solely with the information he's taught in class, and he hasn't taught scanf. Does that even make sense? Can this even be done with cin statements?

Answer (score 2):

Use `scanf("%d/%d %c %d/%d", ...)`. If you want you can skip whitespace between the operator and the operands using `scanf("%d/%d%*[ \t]%c%*[ \t]%d/%d", ...);`

Answer (score 1):

If your professor hasn't taught you scanf() yet, you can get the input using cin then *parse it* using the methods that your professor taught you.

Reading [this](http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/330/ParsingLine/parsingline.html) should help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you can assume that the input is well-formed, you can read a fraction by reading its constituent parts, similar to this:

```
int numerator, denominator;
char slash;
std::cin >> numerator >> slash >> denominator;
```

Wrap that in a function that returns an instance of the data structure you're representing fractions with.

Then handle the operators.